# How to make an image blurry using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am new to OpenCV. How can I make an image blurry using OpenCV in Python?

Comment: What aspect of this particular situation is not covered by existing resources?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make an image blurry, you can use the `GaussianBlur()` method of OpenCV.

The `GaussianBlur()` uses the Gaussian kernel. The height and width of the kernel should be a positive and an odd number.

Then you have to specify the X and Y direction that is `sigmaX` and `sigmaY` respectively. If only one is specified, both are considered the same.

Example:

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("sample_img.jpg")
blur_image = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (7,7), 0)
cv2.imshow('Original Image', img)
cv2.imshow('Blur Image', blur_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

In the above snippet, the actual image is passed to `GaussianBlur()` along with height and width of the kernel and the X and Y directions.

In median blurring, the median of all the pixels of the image is calculated inside the kernel area. The central value is then replaced with the resultant median value. Median blurring is used when there are salt and pepper noise in the image.

To apply median blurring, you can use the `medianBlur()` method of OpenCV.

Example:

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("pynoise.png")
blur_image = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cv2.imshow('Original Image', img)
cv2.imshow('Blur Image', blur_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```